# CSS Background URL Not Binding To Property

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a div with a background image who's url is not being bound when the page loads.  The URL is set in a get method in the code behind.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The HTML:

```
<div class="decorator" style="background: transparent url(<%# HeadlineBackgroundImagePath %>) top center no-repeat; height: <%# HeadlineBackgroundImageHeight %>px;">
```

The code behind:

```
    protected string HeadlineBackgroundImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return ($CompanyContext.Entity as IPPCUpdateEntity).HeadlineBackground.ShortSrc;
        }
    }

    protected int? HeadlineBackgroundImageHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return ($CompanyContext.Entity as IPPCUpdateEntity).HeadlineBackground.Height;
        }
    }
```

When the page loads, I get something like this (notice nothing is in the URL):

```
<div class="decorator" style="background: transparent url() top center no-repeat; height: px;">
```

I've gone into debugger, set a breakpoint on the property, but the site doesn't even call up the property.

Comment: Please show us the actual output code instead of comments. Or is that the bug here...

Comment: Use these tags <%=whatever %>

Comment: The last code section has the output.  The problem is "url()".  There should be a path in there.  The <%# HeadlineBackgroundImagePath %> should be calling the property in the code behind, but it actually doesn't.

Comment: where is set ? where are u setting the value ? Use get-set

Comment: Yes @Ani he is using databinding syntax not Response.Write syntax. He should use <%= blah %> or if he uses <%# blah %> then he may have to call Page.Databind

Comment: When I use <%=, I simply get <div class="decorator" style="background: transparent url(<%= HeadlineBackgroundImagePath %> .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ani's answer got me on the right path, but was only part of the solution.  I set up the property as suggested, but I needed to add one line of code after setting the image path in the code behind.  In the page load event, I set the property and then called Page.DataBind() to get it to work.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HeadlineBackgroundImagePath = ($CompanyContext.Entity as IPPCUpdateEntity).HeadlineBackground.ShortSrc;
            Page.DataBind();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(($CompanyContext.Entity as IPPCUpdateEntity).FloodlightTag))
                floodlightTag.Text = ($CompanyContext.Entity as IPPCUpdateEntity).FloodlightTag;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use get-set :

```
private string _headlineimg ="N/A";
public property HeadlineBackgroundImagePath() As string{
    get{
        return _headlineimg
   }
    set{
        _headlineimg = value
    }
}
```

then On page load event:

```
HeadlineBackgroundImagePath = "whatever";
```

Comment: The problem isn't setting the property.  It's that the HTML isn't calling the property.

Comment: Did you change the tag to :  <%=whatever %> ?

Comment: When I use <%=, I simply get <div class="decorator" style="background: transparent url(<%= HeadlineBackgroundImagePath %> .........  IF I throw runat="server" onto the div tag.  Otherwise it throws an error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks"

Comment: Can you check by adding a breakpoint to see if you are actually getting some value in HeadlineBackgroundImagePath  ?

Comment: It was being set, figured it out though.  Thanks for your help!